# keyup function working fine with all browsers but only in IE its not working

Tags: javascript

```
$("#txtZip").keyup(function(e){});
```

after getting results from ajax call i am using this keyup function for that html element(like pincode)  but its working in all browsers not in internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

are you wrapping your script in ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#txtZip").keyup(function(e){});
});
```